# Mathieu function periodicity problem

Tags: bugs, special-functions, documentation

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and fixed in 10.3.0**

*This is a documentation mistake in `MathieuCharacteristicA`, `MathieuCharacteristicB`, and `MathieuCharacteristicExponent`.*

---

According to the documentation, the Mathieu characteristic function generates parameter a:

> The characteristic value Subscript[a, r] gives the value of the
>   parameter a in y′′+(a-2q cos(2z))y=0 for which the solution has the
>   form e^(i r z) f(z), where f(z) is an even function of z with period
>   2π.

However, I get the function `f` that are periodic of π instead of 2π. Here is the construction of the periodic function f (followed from Input 76 on page 1105 of The Mathematica Guidebook for Symbolics):

```
f[k_, q_, z_] := (MathieuC[MathieuCharacteristicA[k, q], q, z] + I Sign[k] MathieuS[MathieuCharacteristicB[k, q], q, z])/Exp[I k z]
Plot[{Abs@f[3, -1, z], Abs@f[1/3, -1, z]}, {z, -2 π, 2 π}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, GridLines -> {π/2 Range[-3, 3, 2], {}}]
```

[image]

So why does the periodic function `f` have period of π instead of 2π ?

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floquet_theory#Floquet.27s_theorem_applied_to_Mathieu_equation), [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FloquetsTheorem.html), and [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/28.2#iii), the period is supposed to be `Pi`.  I guess the documentation is wrong. -- Now, should we close this as a "simple mistake in the documentation"? ;P  (Unless, I'm wrong, of course.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for the information, it's really helpful! But I guess I would not agree it's a simple mistake. It has been consistently wrong in the documentation page of `MathieuCharacteristicA `, `MathieuCharacteristicB ` and `MathieuCharacteristicExponent`. I was too faithful about the documentation, that I wasted a whole weekend doing completely wrong things :(

Comment: The "simple mistake" remark was a joke.  I appreciate that the frustration and waste of time it has caused you is no joke.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Ah, I see. By the way, have you used MathieuA function in Maple? It's the counterpart of `MathieuCharacteristicA` in Mathematica but I'm wondering why it only accept integer number as argument.

Comment: @MichaelE2 [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/911608/49028) is my problem in detail. Could you show me the documentation page you are referring to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, the characteristic value $a_r$ gives the value of the parameter $a$ in $y′′+(a-2q \cos(2z))\,y=0$ for which the solution has the form $e^{i r z} f(z)$, where $f(z)$ is an even function of $z$ with period $\pi$, not $2\pi$ as stated in the documentation.

See, for instance, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floquet_theory#Floquet.27s_theorem_applied_to_Mathieu_equation), [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FloquetsTheorem.html), or the [Digitial Library of Mathematical Functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/28.2#iii).

The documentation is wrong.